# Gas requirement of function client.<function_name>() high: infinite

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, contract-debugging

I've tried fix that problem. but still i don't know what was wrong

[image]

If someone can fix this problem, please save me. I'm still trying this.

below sample code

```
contract HelloWorld {
    uint private simpleInt;

    function GetValue() public view returns (uint) {
        return simpleInt;
    }

    function SetValue(uint _value) public {
        simpleInt = _value;
    }
}

contract client {
    address obj ;

    function setObject(address _obj) external {
        obj = _obj;
    }

    function UseExistingAddress() public payable returns (uint) {
        HelloWorld myObj = HelloWorld(obj);
        myObj.SetValue(10);
        return myObj.GetValue();
    }
}
```

when i tried to created contract HelloWorld first and next created contract client. I executed setValue method first with that parameter and I got error when i executed useExistingAddress method

[image]

I use Geth window version in my computer and show you genesis.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
  "timestamp": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0xffffffff",
  "difficulty": "0x200",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0100000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {}
}
```

this is my geth command in .bat file

```
start geth --networkid 15 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --datadir "D:\myeth\chaindata" --rpc --rpcapi "eth,web3,miner,admin,personal,net" --rpccorsdomain "*" --unlock 0,1,2,3 --password "D:\myeth\pass.txt"
start geth attach rpc:http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

and this is state when i executed setObject function.

[image]
[image]

I have a question. I set gas limit 30000000. but when i executed setObject function and check logs, gas and transaction cost were same. Is this normal?

please help me.

Comment: Please share your actual code, not a screenshot. (Screenshots are not searchable, so they're of little use to future developers who have the same problem.)

Comment: I updated it. sorry.

Comment: "I got error when i executed useExistingAddress" What error did you get?

Comment: Gas requirement of function client.UseExistingAddress() high: infinite. If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)

Comment: that is in my analysis tab

Comment: That's not an error. That's a warning that you'll see any time there's no bound on the amount of gas needed. (E.g. when you call out to another function.)

Comment: transact to client.UseExistingAddress errored: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction - so it's my error and how can i exceed gas limit?

Comment: I fixed some. Even if i set my gas limit but It was not reflected. how about you?

Comment: Yes, that second error is a real error and generally indicates that the call you're making is going to fail.

Comment: For what it's worth, your code runs fine for me in Remix using the JavaScript VM.

Comment: how about that states? that transaction cost and gas were same?

Comment: No, they weren't the same. Have you tried this? (JavaScript VM in Remix)

Comment: Of course. but i always got state both were same. when i executed it in javascript vm was fine. but when i use this using Web3 provider all of the cost and gas in all transaction states were same.

Comment: When I execute it using JavaScript VM I got error like below

Comment: transact to client.UseExistingAddress errored: VM error: revert.
revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information. - how did you do that?

Comment: Before you said "when i executed it in javascript vm was fine" but now you say you're getting an error?

Comment: Yes. I got error like that. so I think my setting is wrong. But i can't find wrong setting. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I'll fix my setting I still don't know what was wrong. I really appreciate your helping.